# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in D

Tags: php, pdo

i have a problem that really warried me i create a website and I want my users first connect to the site, and then they fill information in a table, and then save the data and redisplay them by id
this is what i'm teying to do

```
$id=#SESSION{idCommercant}
//$mail=$_SESSION['_mail'];
$reponse = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM produit, produit_commerce, commerce, commercant
where produit_commerce.idmagasin=commerce.idMagasin
and produit.idProduit=produit_commerce.idproduit

and  commerce.idCommercant= commercant.idCommercant
and  commercant.idCommercant= :id  ;");

$reponse->execute(array(':id'=>$id)) or die(print_r($reponse->errorInfo()));
```

but this returns the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in D:\wamp\www\it_technology\Affichage\essai.php on line 45
```

Comment: What is `$id=#SESSION{idCommercant}`? What line is `45`?

Comment: What is the line 45 I'd rather ask

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty obvious: on the line of 45 you are trying to cast `$response` object into string. by trying either to echo it or concatenate or whatever. You have to get a data array out of response and then use it:

```
$row = $reponse->fetch();
```

Also note that using of die() is prohibited in general and especially useless with PDO which can die by itself, and perform it way better than if you kill it manually.

Answer (score -1):

Your first line should read $id= $_SESSION['idCommercant'] (I suppose)

As it stands now a single line comment is started right after the = sign. Excecution proceeds on the next line and assigns the value of $response (a PDOStatement) to $id.

In the last line you try to pass this as a parameter to $response->execute() which expects an array of strings, but an array with a PDOStatement is given. It cannot be converted, hence the error.